# Android ndk MD5 hash function string conversion

Tags: c++, android-ndk

Hello I want to try include md5 hash c++ function to my Android NDK project.
I have a problem with types. Eclipse shows me build invalid arguments error with the following message:

> Invalid arguments 'Candidates are: void update(const unsigned char *,
>   unsigned int) void update(const char *,  unsigned int) '

Method:

```
// nifty shortcut ctor, compute MD5 for string and finalize it right away
MD5::MD5(const std::string &text)
{
    init();
    update(text.c_str(), text.length()); //there is problem
    finalize();
}
```

I call this method:

```
// MD5 block update operation. Continues an MD5 message-digest
// operation, processing another message block
void MD5::update(const char input[], size_type length)
{
    // compute number of bytes mod 64
    size_type index = count[0] / 8 % blocksize;

    // Update number of bits
    if ((count[0] += (length << 3)) < (length << 3))
        count[1]++;
    count[1] += (length >> 29);

    // number of bytes we need to fill in buffer
    size_type firstpart = 64 - index;

    size_type i;

    // transform as many times as possible.
    if (length >= firstpart)
    {
        // fill buffer first, transform
        memcpy(&buffer[index], input, firstpart);
        transform(buffer);

        // transform chunks of blocksize (64 bytes)
        for (i = firstpart; i + blocksize <= length; i += blocksize)
            transform(&input[i]);

        index = 0;
    }
    else
        i = 0;

    // buffer remaining input
    memcpy(&buffer[index], &input[i], length - i);
}

//////////////////////////////

// for convenience provide a verson with signed char
void MD5::update(const char input[], size_type length)
{
    update((const unsigned char*)input, length);
}
```

What is wrong, project work normally in Visual Studio but in java NDK I have these problems...
Thank you for help

Comment: Where and how is **size_type** defined? BTW, probably, your copy/paste didn't work well: you have now two functions that both take same parameters.

Comment: It seems you did not post your real code, because both of your `update` functions have an identical signature (both take a signed char array).

Comment: it waa android problem, i import c++ library and wokw for now.. thank you.